# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to a} x^{x^x}$

Tags: limits

I know that $\lim_{x \to 0}x^x = 1$

But how do I apply the above to $\lim_{x \to 0}x^{x^x}$

$\lim_{x \to 0}x^{x^x} = e^{\lim_{x \to 0}x^xlnx}$

(Given that we can only apply limit laws when both $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exists such that

$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) . \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0^1=0$?

Comment: The function $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is continuous at $(0,1)$ (unlike at $(0,0)$), so by taking $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $(0,1)$, we can make $x^y$ arbitrarily close to $0^1=0$.

Comment: What you've written is also all correct, and the limit of that exponent is $-\infty$ by the product rule that you stated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on set of real nos. $\mathbb R$, then you can apply limit rules.But if you consider set of extended reals, that is the set $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$ (here $\infty $ is assumed to be a no. for which it is true that if $y\in \mathbb R$, then $y\lt \infty $. Similarly, $-\infty $ is defined as a no. which is smaller than any given real number), then limit rules don't always work. One example is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 1{|x|}+\lim_{x\to 0}(1-\frac 1{|x|})=\infty -\infty\ne \lim_{x\to 0}(\frac 1{|x|}+1-\frac 1{|x|})=1.$

Now, $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^x\ln x$ does not exist in $\mathbb R$, in other words the limit does not exist finitely. 
But the limit exists in $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$ and infact $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x\ln x=-\infty$.

What existence of this limit means is that given any $t\lt 0$,there exists a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $0\lt x\lt \delta\implies x^x \ln x\lt t\implies e^{x^x\ln x}\lt e^t$. Now note that for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists a $t_\epsilon\lt 0$ such that $e^{t_\epsilon}\lt \epsilon$ 
Therefore, for any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is a $\delta_\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $0\lt x\lt \delta_\epsilon\implies e^{x^x\ln x}\lt \epsilon\implies \lim_{x\to 0}e^{x^x\ln x}=0.$

In other words, $e^{x^x\ln x}$ tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

If we compose Taylor series, we have
$$f(x)=x^{x^x}=x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {P_{n-2}}{(n-1)!} \big[x \log(x)\big]^n$$ where the $P_n$'s are polynomials of degree $n$ in $t=\log(x)$. The first ones are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(t) \\
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & t+1 \\
 4 & t^2+3 t+1 \\
 5 & t^3+6 t^2+7 t+1 \\
 6 & t^4+10 t^3+25 t^2+15 t+1 \\
 7 & t^5+15 t^4+65 t^3+90 t^2+31 t+1 \\
 8 & t^6+21 t^5+140 t^4+350 t^3+301 t^2+63 t+1 \\
 9 & t^7+28 t^6+266 t^5+1050 t^4+1701 t^3+966 t^2+127 t+1 
\end{array}
\right)$$ in which we can find some interesting patterns.

Even with few terms, these expansions match quite well the original function for the range $0\leq x \leq 1$. The same for the integral. For illustartion purposes, consider
$$g_p(x)=x+\sum_{n=2}^p \frac {P_{n-2}}{(n-1)!} \big[x \log(x)\big]^n$$ and the norm
$$\Phi_p=\int_0^1 \Big[f(x)-g_p(x)\big]^2\,dx$$ Here are the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \color{red}{10^8} \Phi_p\\
 2 & 2790.43 \\
 3 & 224.866 \\
 4 & 2.50098 \\
 5 & 0.07587 \\
 6 & 0.00219 \\
 7 & 0.00002
\end{array}
\right)$$